# Email server with DigitalOcean and Webmin Does not send to Yahoo, Hotmail

Tags: digital-ocean, webmin, webmail

I been following tutorials on how to setup my own SMTP server for Email marketing using Digital ocean Droplets and Webmin
I came to a point where I have installed the Webmin using PUtty, set up DKIM and SPF, MX etc. respectively. But I used a Free domain name set up on `freenom.com` which is `movattidesignsitaliano.gq` for setup of the SMTP server.

Having tested, I saw it in my Gmail in the Spam Folder. Then the Horde Webmail (Which happens to be my Office email) I saw in Junk folder as well, but for the Yahoo and Hotmail, I did not even see it there at all.

Checking inside the Webmail , I saw something like this :

```
This is the mail system at host movattidesignsitaliano.gq.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<xxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com>: host
    hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.22.161] said: 550 5.7.1
    Unfortunately, messages from [143.198.57.6] weren't sent. Please contact
    your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block
    list (S3150). You can also refer your provider to
    http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
    [DB8EUR06FT056.eop-eur06.prod.protection.outlook.com] (in reply to MAIL
    FROM command)

<xxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com>: host
    hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.22.161] said: 550 5.7.1
    Unfortunately, messages from [143.198.57.6] weren't sent. Please contact
    your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block
    list (S3150). You can also refer your provider to
    http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
    [DB8EUR06FT056.eop-eur06.prod.protection.outlook.com] (in reply to MAIL
    FROM command)

<xxxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com>: host mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[67.195.204.79] said: 553
    5.7.2 [TSS09] All messages from 143.198.57.6 will be permanently deferred;
    Retrying will NOT succeed. See
    https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes (in reply to MAIL FROM
    command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; movattidesignsitaliano.gq
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: AFFECC3F07
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; support@movattidesignsitaliano.gq
Arrival-Date: Thu, 11 Mar 2021 08:19:51 +0000 (UTC)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; xxxxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;xxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.7.1 Unfortunately, messages from [143.198.57.6]
    weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of
    their network is on our block list (S3150). You can also refer your
    provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
    [DB8EUR06FT056.eop-eur06.prod.protection.outlook.com]

Final-Recipient: rfc822; xxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;xxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.7.1 Unfortunately, messages from [143.198.57.6]
    weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of
    their network is on our block list (S3150). You can also refer your
    provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
    [DB8EUR06FT056.eop-eur06.prod.protection.outlook.com]

Final-Recipient: rfc822; xxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;xxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.2
Remote-MTA: dns; mta6.am0.yahoodns.net
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 553 5.7.2 [TSS09] All messages from 143.198.57.6 will be
    permanently deferred; Retrying will NOT succeed. See
    https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes
From    Charles Schwab Online
Date    Today 09:19
hi man
```

This has been happening for quite sometime now. What do I appear not to be setting correctly?

Comment: Did you read the error messages? They are fairly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, you should not be using a Digital Ocean droplet for marketing email. You should be using a service like Mailgun, Amazon SES, Postmark, or similar.

Digital Oceans networks have a bad reputation for email and mail servers on them will be frequently flagged as spam because:

- Digital Ocean makes no effort to restrict the creation of mail servers or screen the people allowed to run mail servers on their network.
- People frequently start spam campaigns from their network which causes their entire subnets to be flagged.

Subnets that are flagged as spam can only be removed from the blacklist flagging them by the provider that owns them. This means that unlike when your own IP/Mailserver is flagged, you have to get Digital Ocean to get the removal pushed through. They will not work with some blacklists.

Running a mail server on Digital Ocean never used to be this difficult, but then people started abusing it with mass email and marketing campaigns.

Use a proper service for this.